# How can i force the user to input a correct data?

Tags: python, error-handling, while-loop

i have got a little problem with while loop:

1. I am creating a dict:

```
reader = csv.reader(open('prices.csv', 'r'))
    prices = {}
    for row in reader:
        k, v = row
        prices[k] = v
    list_of_types = list(prices.keys())
```

then i try to get a type of a product with a function:

```
type = get_type(list_of_types)
```

```
def get_type(list_of_types):

    # Printing the list which contains all the keys of a dictionary
    print("\n")
    print("list of available concrete types:")
    print(" ________________________________________")
    print(list_of_types)
    print(" ‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾‾")

# Get a concrete type
    type = input("Please enter the type of a concrete: ").lower()
    while type not in ['c10', 'c15', 'c20', 'c25', 'c30', 'c37']:
        print("Sorry, your response was not loud enough.")
        type = input("Please enter the type of a concrete: ").lower()
```

but it doesn/t work.

I would like it to ask the user for a type of concrete, than check if it is in the list, if so to return this type, else to repromt the user for a correct type.
Could you please help me?

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't work"?  What does it **actually do**?

Comment: You have no `return type` statement in `get_type()`.

Comment: Shouldn't the test be `while type not in list_of_types:`?

Comment: Also don't call your variable `type`, that shadows the preexisting `type`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

## Get a concrete type

```
while True:
    type = input("Please enter the type of a concrete: ").lower()
    if type not in ['c10', 'c15', 'c20', 'c25', 'c30', 'c37']:
        continue
    else:
        return type
```